# Adding Items in Combobox using Input Box (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a user form on which i have one add button which pop-ups the input box to enter the value and then add it in the combobox. However, when i unload the user form and again load it, that item is not there.

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub MetroButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MetroButton1.Click

    Dim addnew As String

    addnew = InputBox("Please Add New Department.", "Add New Department", vbInformation)

    Me.ComboBox2.Items.Add(addnew)
    Me.ComboBox2.Update()
End Sub
```

Please advise.

Thanks
Salman

Comment: Of course it is not there - it is *data* created and added at *runtime*.  If you want it to persist, you need to save it somewhere and reload it.

Comment: recall that your new form has its own set of variables on the stack...you arent loading the same object...you could technically create lots of instances of the same form on the same screen with different values in the combobox

Comment: Open the Settings page of the project properties and add a setting of type `StringCollection`. You can access that via `My.Settings` in code and use it to store the items between sessions. Note that you will have to add an item to the collection, close the dialogue, then remove that item again in order to prevent the setting being `Nothing` by default. After doing that, you'll notice an XML snippet left behind, which is what forces the creation of the collection object.

Answer (score 0):

I create a new project from scratch and complete it.Just add these codes to your form.
 in addition you can download full working project form [here](http://oranusnovin.com/dl_files/Projects/oranusnovin.com.zip)

```
 Private Sub MetroButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MetroButton1.Click
        Dim addnew As String

        addnew = InputBox("Please Add New Department.", "Add New Department", vbInformation)

        Me.ComboBox2.Items.Add(addnew)
        Me.ComboBox2.Update()
        '-----------------------
        Dim fn As String = Application.StartupPath + "\cb.txt"
        Dim a(Me.ComboBox2.Items.Count - 1) As String
        '--------------------------------------------
        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.ComboBox2.Items.Count - 1
            a(i) = Me.ComboBox2.Items(i).ToString
        Next
        IO.File.WriteAllLines(fn, a)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim fn As String = Application.StartupPath + "\cb.txt"
        If IO.File.Exists(fn) = False Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim a As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(fn)
        '-------------------------------
        Me.ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        For Each c As String In a
            If c <> vbCrLf Then
                Me.ComboBox2.Items.Add(c)
            End If
        Next
        '----------------------------------
    End Sub
```

Comment: In a properly configured filesystem, `Application.StartupPath` will not be writable. Perhaps you could edit your answer to use somewhere in the program data directory.

Comment: It's working without any problem.You can test attached project.After that you are right , you can change the txt file path to every where on your hard drive!

Comment: If the program is installed under the "Program Files" directory then a normal user will not have write access in that directory.